# Summability of double partial derivatives of $\frac{1}{|x|}$ in dimension $3$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, partial-derivative, lp-spaces, laplacian

I know the fact that its laplacian is equal to the Dirac delta function. However, is it true that its partial derivatives of order 2 belong to $L^{1}(\mathbb{R}^3)$? And how should  I show that, in case this is true? I had thought of calculating derivatives in standard coordinates and then pass to spherical coordinates to see if something got simpler, but I am not sure this would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The derivatives of order 2 of $u(x)=\frac{1}{|x|}$does not belong to $L^1$. The sum $\left(\partial^2_1+ \partial^2_2+\partial^2_3 \right) u= \delta_0 \notin L^1$ so at least one of them is not in $L^1$ (and by symmetry none of them).

As you mentioned an other option is to compute these derivatives:
$$\partial_i u =\frac{x_i}{|x|^3}$$
so:
$$\partial_{ij}^2 u = \begin{cases}\frac{1}{|x|^3}-\frac{3x_i^2} {|x^5|} \text{ if } i=j \\
-3\frac{x_i x_j}{|x|^5} \text{ if } i \neq j \end{cases}$$
but none of these functions are in $L^1$. For example using spherical coordinates you obtain
$$\iiint_{\mathbb{R}^3} \frac{x_1 x_2}{|x|^5} dx_1d_x2d_x3 =\int_0^\infty \int_0^{2 \pi} \int_0^\pi \frac{r^2 \sin(\theta)^2 |\cos(\phi) \sin(\phi)|}{r^5} r^2 \sin(\theta) d\theta d\phi dr=\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{r} \left(\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\pi \sin(\theta)^3 \frac{1}{2} |\sin(2\phi)| d\theta d\phi \right) dr=+\infty$$.

The same behavior emerges in all cases: a singularity like $\frac{1}{r}$ which is not integrable.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I ecplained it wrong. What I wanted to show is that the convolution of those derivatives with a function belonging to $L^1$ belongs to $L^1$, so the Dirac delta doesn’t bother me.

Comment: Can I show that those derivatives behave like a properly rescaled Dirac delta? Like the double derivative with respect to only 1 variable behave like a third of the laplacian (by simmetry this should hold)

Comment: The singularity should appear in the case of the laplacian as well. So shouldn’t there be a way to get a properly rescaled Dirac delta eith the double detivatives as well?

Comment: @tommy1996q It is very interesting question :-). The $1/r$ singularity is not too bad as you are in a weak $L^1$ space. But unfortunately Young inequality for $L^p/L^{q,\infty}$ spaces does not hold for $p=q=1$. So  you are in a way in a "critical" case so it is maybe possible to have such property but one must use some properties of $1/|x|$ to do so.

Comment: Well, if $p=1$ is a problem, feel free to take higher values. The key point here is I want to see how to work with those derivatives in a useful way, like it is done for the laplacian

Comment: Also I think you missed a minus sign in the first derivtive, they should be the opposite

Comment: The fact is that I need estimates for the double derivatives, because I am using Sobolev spaces and I need to have them. Either that or get an estimate of second derivatives from the laplacian. The problem is that the sum of the three double derivatives behave very well, but single derivatives behave very very bad. The only thing I can think of is trying to arrive at the same expression of the laplacian by some neat trick. For instance dividing the integral in three proper pieces, change variables accordingly in them such that I get to integrate the laplacian in a subset of the sphere.